# Image slider that resizes only images that are bigger than a fixed size?

Tags: javascript, image, slider, slideshow

I need an image slider which resizes the images **only** if its needed (the size of the image is bigger than the div containing the slider).

I've tried with AnythingSlider, but when I set the width and height to the div containing the slider, the images that are smaller than the div are stretched. I don't want them to be stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a check in javascript/jquery to see what the size of the image is. If it's bigger than the desired dimension you can just scale it down.

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution, but I just wanted to know if there is an JS slider that already has the ability to do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

play with this . add condition for styling

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/create-a-resizable-image-grid-with-jquery

http://demos.webdesignledger.com/jquery_image_grid/example2.htm

Comment: Thanks for the links, but they don't seem to solve my problem, I'm just looking for an slideshow of images that only resizes images that have a greater size than the slideshow div size.